# iphone initial portrait orientation load is giving element width of landscape view

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I have a div set to `width: 100%`.  When I load it initially in the portrait view of the iphone the element width is picking up at `480px`.

The odd thing about this is that when I console log the width at load I am getting `320px`.  Also, if I manually change the orientation to landscape and then back to portrait then the element is getting the correct sizing.

I have tried a handful of suggestions to the meta viewport tag, but nothing seems to be working.  Here is the current tag info:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimal-ui">
```

Also, when I change the zoom after initial load, then the element gets the correct sizing.

Any suggestions on how I can get the right size at initial load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to delete this post, but since someone upvoted it I figured I would provide the answer.  The issue was that this element had `position: fixed`.   I simply added `position: absolute` for the media query on mobile and it is now functioning properly. :)